# Getting Spring (and other libraries) in a Maven world

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jar

I am following an online tutorial, and am stuck trying to get Spring libraries to run things with.  The instructions are either a little out of date or assume I know how to do things in a Maven world that I do not.

They give web addresses on the Spring site from which they say I can "download the jars".  But you can't download jars from any of them; evidently what you can do is find pom.xml fragments and use them to download jars.  If you know how.

For example: the tutorial says:

> Finally, following is the list of Spring and other libraries to be
>   included in your web application. You simply drag these files and drop
>   them in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.
>
> commons-logging-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.asm-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.beans-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.context-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.core-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.expression-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet-x.y.z.jar
>
> org.springframework.web-x.y.z.jar
>
> spring-web.jar

I love the "simply" here.

I have many but not all of these (version 3.2.4).  I have googled the library names and used jarfinder for the ones I don't have, but haven't found them all.  It seems to me I'm flailing around a bit, just trying this and that until something works.  I hate that.

I'm hoping someone can give me a set of steps I should follow when faced with this sort of thing, since we're faced with it all the time.  Do I need to stop my current study of programming and learn Maven inside and out so that I can configure the bloody system so I can program again?

Comment: you can use the pom fragment to download the jars to your local `.m2` folder and then you can use it on a non maven projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a maven project you have?

If so in the pom.xml you just need to place the “pom fragments” in the xml.

i.e. between the dependencies tags. For example,

```
<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.2</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Once you have done that run maven install. Under Eclipse it is: run as > maven install.

That will download all the dependences i.e. jars you have listed into the you local maven repository.

I think the default is C:\Users\yourName\.m2\repository

Comment: Sorry, should have said explicitly that it is not a maven project -- I thought the list of jars needed for the example might have made that clear.  It appears that Spring forcefully assumes that everyone uses Maven, or at least knows it well, but I was hoping to study Spring things without it.

Comment: Just create an empty maven project then put the fragments in the pom and run it. That will download everything you need then you can use those jars in any project.

Answer (score 1):

Found most of the needed jar files here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/CatalogJar.htm

while I downloaded commons-logging here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2

Answer (score 0):

My advice is, stop study you program language, Java I guess and learn how to integrate maven dependencies of Spring in your Maven project.

http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/

You cannot start the house from the roof

Comment: So, the programming language is the roof?  It's a strange, strange world we live in, Master Jack...  Thanks for the spring.io reference, though, it's as close as anything I've seen to actual instructions about this on the Spring site.

Comment: I believe than before start coding you need to learn your project management technology

Comment: Maven is a tool for managing dependencies among components of a software application, not a 'project management technology' by any stretch of the imagination.  And the idea that before we code we must learn all the tricks of a tool that is not necessary for our coding task is backwards.  I suppose it's consistent with thinking of the programming language as the 'roof', but consistency by itself does not indicate sound logic.